# mongoose query to collection not returning results?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a model defined as such:

`game.js`

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var Game = new Schema({
  game: String,
  lobby_size: Number });

module.exports = mongoose.model('games', Game, 'game_list');
```

and I am attempting to GET all entries in the collection 'game_list' and print them to `console.log` for debugging

```
games.js

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Games = require('../models/game.js');

router.get('/list', function(req, res) {
  Games.find({}, function(err, docs) {
    console.log(docs);
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Here is my code for connecting to the db:

`app.js`

```
// connect mongoose to db
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/angulobby');
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error: '));
db.on('open', function() {
  console.log('connected to database.');
});
```

When I run `db.game_list.find({})` in the mongoDB shell I get:

`{ "_id" : ObjectId("595541d1d01f064117614a28"), "game" : "Counter-Strike: Global Offensive", "lobby_size" : 5 }`

so I know the collection is populated, but when I run the `/list` api call the console.log only prints `[]`

Thank you all in advance for your help!

Comment: Check that you call your API after your server connects to database

Comment: All things being equal this should work. Are you sure your existing collection is actually in the `angulobby` database? By default when you connect through the mongo shell the database namespace is `test`, so make sure you did not actually create it there instead. You can also set `mongoose.set('debug',true)` which will log the connection and all commands issued to mongodb. But the most likely explanation is that you are simply looking at the wrong database namespace or server.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks, that ended up being it after much trial and error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the solution. In my local mongoDB server I was not properly setting the database to the `/angulobby` database so it was not receiving the information in the collection. Issuing the command `use angulobby` fixed it and I can now receive the correct query responses.